# How to directly display login screen on welcome/start page in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I work on my first project, app based on ASP.NET Core 6 MVC with default identity Razor pages. I'm working on .NET 6 and using EF Core 6. The app is a customer management system and it's for internal use only.

I have implemented scaffolded identity, it works properly when accessing by its route: `/Identity/Account/Login` but the question is:
how to display login form on welcome / home page, protecting all other content except login form from unauthorized access? I mean the user who enters: `mydomain.com` should see only login/register page.

I.e.: when I place `[Authorize]` attribute on the `HomeController`, it doesn't redirect me to the login page, I just get a http 404 error. So is it a matter of authorization, routing issue or just HTML layout topic?

I have dug through tons of posts and couldn't find the answer. Maybe I misunderstood the problem?

Regards,
Kristo

Comment: It usually returns 401 if it's authorization error. You can try remove [Authorize] and see if the endpoint is reachable, to single out the actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code in the startup file this will help you navigates mydomain.com to the Login page.

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Identity/Account/Login", "");
    });
});
```

If you want to protect all other content, you can use the `[Authorize]` attribute at a global level.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

You have to allow the access to the user for the login or registration page add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute in the PageModel class.

regarding the 404 error seems like system does not know where to redirect unauthorized users.by using below code it will redirect unauthorized user to the login page.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
});
```

Comment: Half done success :) Proper configuring of LoginPath helped with redirection, however I can't use options in MapRazorPages method as it throws an error in VS, that method is not taking any arguments (exactly: no overload takes 1 argument)

Comment: @kkkristo if you are facing trouble with the method not taking argument you could set the redirect in the home controller to achieve your requirement ` public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { area = "Identity" });
        }

        return View();
    }` do not forgot to allow access to the login or registration pages

Comment: Tried this but received 404 error saying there's no page under: https://localhost:44331/Account/Login?area=Identity. The proper path is: localhost:443331/Identity/Account/Login but I can't solve how to set it up in controller. Im trying to get from Home Controller to Login Razor Page in Area "Identity"

Comment: could you please check if you have app.MapRazorPages(); middleware in your program or startup file

Comment: Yes, I have:
`code`
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession();
app.UseRouting(); 
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();    
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
`code`

Comment: @kkkristo could you try adding [Authorize] in the home controller and app.MapRazorPages(); in the program file and try again to access the site

Comment: if  it still does not work could you please share the minimal repro sample with us.

Comment: Meanwhile I put an answer that solution is found with your great help :) The only thing left is redirecting from controller to single Razor page, but I'll ask it in seperate post.

Comment: @kkkristo glad to hear the suggestion help you to resolve the problem. i would like to request you to mark your post as answer that will help other user

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The login screen appears as first, after entering domain url: i.e. mydomain.com - it was a matter of setting up the authorization in services, as @Jalpa Panchal suggested, and also configuring proper login path, again from  @Jalpa Panchal answer.

Having that, pure login screen/page with only login forms was just a matter of html layout. Thank you.

While looking for a solution, another problem appeared, how in controller redirect to single Razor pages, i.e. those placed in Areas/identity/Account or ..Account/Manage. But this is slightly off topic for here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set defult like this :
in startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login }/{id?}");
    );
}
```

Comment: Can I really? The default identity pages are razor pages located in solution in Areas/Identity/Account/ path and they don't use controllers or views to my understanding.

Comment: @kkkristo dear if you are using razor pages , of course you have action in controllers that's mean you can set the controller name and action , ignore the UI path , the method in your controller will get the view